# Use filename to determine file type

Tags: c#, strings

This is legacy, so I'm not really looking for improvements on architectural approach.

Here's what the method does:

1. Extracts filename from a string containing full file path (passed in as parameter)
2. Checks to see if the filename extracted is not null or empty or just white spaces
3. If check in step 2 passes, then it uses naming conventions in the filename, to determine the logical "Type" for the file as follows:

   1. If filename contains `__Import__`, then set`Type` to `Source Data`
   2. If filename contains `__Export__`, then set`Type` to `Destination Data`
   3. If filename contains `__Transform__`, then set`Type` to `Transformational Data`
   4. If none of the conditions from 3.1 through 3.3 are met, then default the "Type" to `General`.

Is there a way to make the `if...else if... else if...` block more concise, and elegant without loss of functionality?

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
{
    // extract filename only
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);
    var fileDataType = string.Empty;

    // if filename is not empty
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
    {
        // if... else... to determine type of file contents based on file name convention
        // legacy code, so not looking for architectural improvements etc... :)
        if (fileName.Contains("__Import__"))
        {
            fileDataType = "Source Data";
        }
        else if (fileName.Contains("__Export__"))
        {
            fileDataType = "Destination Data";
        }
        else if (fileName.Contains("__Transform__"))
        {
            fileDataType = "Transformational Data";
        }
        else
        {
            fileDataType = "General";
        }
    }

    return fileDataType;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain what your code is doing first.

Comment: Apologies, thought it was "self describing"... my bad. I've added the explanation to my question.

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/200766/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: @SamOnela I looked at the site goals link you provided and you are right. The title looks appropriate :)

Answer (score 5):

I find the cleanest way is to replace the ugly `if/else if/else` with a dictionary:

```
private static IDictionary<string, string> FileDataTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    ["Import"] = "Source Data",
    // ..
}
```

The also not so pretty `Contains` can be replaced with a nice regex that will grow or shirnk automatically if you add/remove mappings:

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);
    var fileContentsMatch = Regex.Match(fileName, $"__(?<Type>{string.Join("|", FileDataTypes.Keys)})__", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return
        fileContentsMatch.Success && FileDataTypes.TryGetValue(fileContentsMatch.Groups["Type"].Value, out var fileDataType) 
            ? fileDataType 
            : FileDataTypes[string.Empty];  
}
```

Notice that both the dictionary and the regex are case insensitive. You should always make paths case insensitive in Windows. You are lucky that this worked for so long.

*(Dislaimer: It's just an example so I was to lazy to implement all the empty/null checks)*

Answer (score 3):

The method you have provided looks clean, is short and is easy to understand. It does what it should do but calls `Contains()` in the worst case 3 times which could be avoided.

A filedatatype other than `General` can only happen if at least the delimiter `__` is found twice. So why don't we [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) the filname and if we get an array which length is at least `3` we have something to work with.

Let us assume the filename without extension reads `SomeFile__Export__SomeMoreText` if we call `Split()` using `__` as splitting argument we would get `{"SomeFile", "Export", "SomeMoreText"}` now we can easily iterate over the array starting at the second element and ending at the element before last and using a `switch` on each element to gain the desired filedatatype.

Overall this would look like

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
{

    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName)) { return string.Empty; }

    var possibleFileDataTypes = fileName.Split(new string[] { "__" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    if (possibleFileDataTypes.Length < 3) { return "General"; }

    for (var i = 1; i < possibleFileDataTypes.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        switch (possibleFileDataTypes[i])
        {
            case "Import":
                return "Source Data";

            case "Export":
                return "Destination Data";

            case "Transform":
                return "Transformational Data";
        }
    }
    return "General";
}
```

and produces the following results

```
GetFileDataType(string.Empty) -> string.Emtpty
GetFileDataType(null) -> string.Emtpty
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\Text__Export__SomeOtherText.txt") -> "Destination Data"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\Text__SomeOtherText__SomeMoreText.txt") -> "General"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\Some__File__Import__Some__More__Text.txt") -> "Source Data"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\__Transform__Some__More__Text.txt") -> "Transformational Data"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\__Export__.txt") -> "Destination Data"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\__Export.txt") -> "General"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\____.txt") -> "General"
GetFileDataType(@"C:\folder\____.txt") -> "General"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're searching through the file name for each type until you find one.  If you use the `__` as delimiters and find the indexes of the string between them, you will only search the whole string once.

By extracting the substring with the type, now you can use a `switch` block to return the appropriate value:

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
{
    const string Delimiter = "__";
    // extract filename only
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);
    var fileDataType = string.Empty;
    int indexA = fileName.IndexOf(Delimiter);
    string type = "";
    if(indexA != -1 && indexA != 0)
    {
        indexA += 2;
        int indexB = fileName.IndexOf(Delimiter, indexA);
        if(indexB != -1)
        {
            type = fileName.Substring(indexA, indexB - indexA);
        }
    }
    switch(type)
    {
        case "Import":
            return "Source Data";
        case "Export":
            return "Destination Data";
        case "Transform":
            return "Transformational Data";
        default:
            return "General";
    }

}
```

If the string is empty or malformed "General" will be returned.  Because the check for this is in one place it can easily be changed, if desired.

Comment: You can just use `.Trim('_')` to remove the leading and trailing underscores ;-)

Comment: Oh, or not... I now see it can by anywhere... well, then let's regex it.

Comment: That would probably work.  But typically filenames aren't very long and unless they're processing millions of filenames, I'm not sure if there would be any appreciable performance gain.

Comment: I think too we can ignore performance here but I find `__(?<Type>Import|Export|Transform)__` is much more readable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that construct

Comment: @t3chb0t `__(?<Type>Import|Export|Transform)__` is a regex solution, right?

Comment: @Shiva exactly, it's the pattern that matches the names and stores the match in the named group `Type`.

Comment: This doesn't produce the same result like the original code. For `__Transform__SomeMoreText` it returns "General", for `null` it throws an exception,  for `string.Empty` it returns "General" instead of `string.empty`, for `__Some__Export__SomeMoreText` it returns "General" instead of `Destination Data`

Answer (score 1):

A different approach based on the idea to use something like a dictonary (t3chb0t's answer) is using two arrays of strings internally. One to check if this "string-component" is present in the file name, the other one to return the file type.
Using these two you need to iterate the first array and return from the second array using same index if you find something.
This removes the if/else structure and seems to be easy to read to me, eventough (or maybe because) it is not as advanced as the other answers and keeps the contains().

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
        {
            // extract filename only
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
                return string.Empty;

            String[] fileNameComponents = { "__Import__", "__Export__", "__Transform__" };
            String[] fileTypes = { "Source Data", "Destination Data", "Transformational Data" };            

            for (int i = 0; i < fileNameComponents.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fileName.Contains(fileNameComponents[i]))
                    return fileTypes[i];
            }

            return "General";
        }
```

This approach only aims at the core of the question (removing the if/else) whitout considering any improvments to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using a declarative approach instead of an imperative one allows a more expressive code.

```
private static string GetFileDataType(string fullFileNameWithPath)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameWithPath);
    return matchingRules.First(tuple => tuple.Item1(fileName)).Item2;
}
```

With `matchingRules` declared as follow:

```
var matchingRules = new List<(Func<string, bool>, string)>();
matchingRules.Add((f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) && f.Contains("__Import__"), "Source Data"));
matchingRules.Add((f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) && f.Contains("__Export__"), "Destination Data"));
matchingRules.Add((f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f) && f.Contains("__Transform__"), "Transformational Data"));
matchingRules.Add((f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f), "General"));
matchingRules.Add((f => true, string.Empty));
```

There are two drawbacks with this solution however:

1. Since each condition should be auto-sufficient, one has to repeat the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` many times
2. Rules ordering matters (not a real drawback because the same ordering also applies with the imperative approach)